# How to create a marker on a existing plot on axes1 in Matlab GUIDE?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have been trying to add a marker to my plot but I have failed so far. This is the piece of code I am working on:

```
v = evalin('base','a matrix in my workspace which is 1000 by 1');
  plot(v, 'Parent', handles.axes2);
  for frames = 2:handles.frameCount-1
      axes(handles.axes1);
      imshow(handles.videoStruct(frames).cdata);
      set(handles.text3, 'String', num2str(frames));
      drawnow;
      pause(1/handles.videoObject.FrameRate);
      axes(handles.axes2);
      hold on;
      plot(frames, v(frames), '.r');
  end
```

I have two axes in my gui. axes1 is used to display a video and has no problems. "v" is plotted in axes 2 before the video display and I would like to add a marker to it which will "move" according to which frame the for loop is at.

The last plot(frames, v(frames)... line works but plots points on axes2.

I have 2 options:

1. Somehow delete the last marker plot when the loop moves to the next iteration. Actually I don't want to prefer this because I will implement a slider to control that marker in the future.
2. Any easier way to create a marker on a plot without plotting it over again :)

Thank you very much from now on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Basically do not call plot inside the loop.  It comes with a bunch of overhead which is slow.  Call it everything outside the loop.  Then inside use the handles to update the marker x & ydata, the images CData, and the text.

```
v = evalin('base','a matrix in my workspace which is 1000 by 1');
plot(handles.axes2. v);
hold(handles.axes2,'on');
%USE these handles in the loop
markH = plot(handles.axes2, 1, v(1), '.r'); %Initial plot and get handle toLine.
imH = imshow(handles.videoStruct(1).cdata, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

for frames = 2:handles.frameCount-1
    % Do no replot just set x, y, & cdata, etc.
    set(markH,'XData',frames,'YData',v(vframes))
    set(imH, 'CData',handles.videoStruct(frames).cdata);
    set(handles.text3, 'String', num2str(frames));
    drawnow;
    pause(1/handles.videoObject.FrameRate);
 end
```

Note: I assumed the first frame & was `index` 1 even though your loop started at 2.  However, if that is not correct then you can easily swap out the 1s for 2s in the calls outside of the loop.